# can i know what's problem in my simple python code when i use readlines?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I'm python beginner using jupyter-lab and i'm trying to open the text file and want to get the data from text file. Even though it is very simple code, return is weird.

what is problem?????

My code:

```
import os

f=open("C:/Users/dfdfdfd/Desktop/python/list.txt","rt")

lines = f.readlines

lines
```

----------------return------------------

```
<function TextIOWrapper.readlines(hint=-1, /)>
```

Comment: `readlines` is a function and not an attribute of `f`. You shoule be calling it as `f.readlines()`

Comment: note, `readlines()` is a bit of an outdated part of the API, you should just use `lines = list(f)`, or perhaps better yet, just iterate over the file object directly if you can handle things line by line

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

readlines is callable.

```
with open("C:/Users/dfdfdfd/Desktop/python/list.txt","rt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```